# Adjoints and Inner Product Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

The proposition states that if $V$ is a finite dimensional IPS and $\ \phi : V \rightarrow V$ is a linear operator, then $\phi$ has an adjoint $\phi^*$ and if the matrix of $\phi$ wrt to an orthonormal basis $B$ is $A$, then the matrix of $\phi^*$ wrt to $B$ is $A^{\dagger}$ (the complex conjugate of $A$).
The last part of the proof of this proposition is what I'm having trouble with - My notes state that since $\beta_{B} : \mathbb{R}^N$ or $\mathbb{C}^N \rightarrow V$ is an isomorphism *(it doesn't state why this is - is it just a fact?)* 
$\phi^* := \beta_{B} \circ \phi_{A^{\dagger}} \circ \beta_{B}^{-1}$ $ \ $ satisfies $< \phi(\beta_{B}(x)) , \beta_{B}(y) >$ *(where did this come from?)* = $<\beta_{B}(x) , \phi^{*}(\beta_{B}(y))>$ *(How is it equal to this?)*
Perhaps I'm being incredibly slow but I really can't get my head around it so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The defining property of the (classical) adjoint is $\langle \phi(x), y \rangle = \langle x, \phi^*(y) \rangle$

Comment: I understand that but I can't apply it in this case - I think I need to see it done step by step...

Comment: Perhaps you should write down explicitly what $\beta_B$ is, especially if you don't see why it is an isomorphism

Comment: $\beta_{B} : \mathbb{F}^{n} \rightarrow V$ defined by $\beta_{B}(x_{1},...,x_{n}) = x_{1}v_{1}+...+x_{n}v_{n}$ where $v_{1},...,v_{n}$ is a basis of $V$ I can see why it is an isomorphism but why does that imply the resulting expressions?